# How to access a variable in a dataset if the variable name is stored in a variable?

Tags: data-structures, dataset, matlab

I have a [dataset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasetclass.html) that has a single column that is called `A`. In can access that column using:

```
ds.A;
```

However, I would like to store the name variable name in a variable so that I can do something like that:

```
colName = 'A';
ds.colName;
```

However, this does not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.subsref.html) instead:

```
ds.(colName)
```

This is often called [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html), and works in regular `struct` as well

---

Alternative ways:

```
% find index of variable
varsNames = get(ds,'VarNames');
colIdx = find(strcmp(varsNames,colName), 1, 'first');

ds(:,colIdx)

ds.(colIdx)
```